# Hydra that executes interactive search

Tags: isearch, keyboard-macros, hydra

What I want is an easy-to-use hydra for macro execution.  Typically I execute a keyboard macro a few times (e), and then might want to repeat infinitely until the end of a buffer (u).  Sometimes I need to search forward or backward before continuing with keyboard macro execution.

What I have is a steaming pile of not-quite-working whats-it.

I have to use foreign-keys to search. This seems wrong.  Without foreign keys the searches don't accept any input.  Even with, if my search term contains a hydra key, then it does that instead.

I must be doing something wrong. Please help!

```
(defhydra hydra-keyboard-macros (:columns 6 :foreign-keys run)
  ("e" kmacro-end-or-call-macro-repeat "execute")
  ("u" (lambda()
         (interactive)
         (let ((current-prefix-arg 0))
           (call-interactively #'kmacro-end-or-call-macro)))
   "unlimited")
  ("s" isearch-forward-regexp "search")
  ("r" isearch-backward-regexp "reverse")
  ("'" edit-last-kbd-macro "edit")
  ("q" nil "quit"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x e") #'hydra-keyboard-macros/kmacro-end-or-call-macro-repeat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will do what you want:

```
(defhydra hydra-keyboard-macros (:columns 6 :foreign-keys run)
  ("e" kmacro-end-or-call-macro-repeat "execute")
  ("u" (lambda()
         (interactive)
         (let ((current-prefix-arg 0))
           (call-interactively #'kmacro-end-or-call-macro)))
   "unlimited")
  ("s" (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (isearch-forward-regexp)
    (hydra-keyboard-macros/body))  "search" :color blue)
  ("r" (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (isearch-backward-regexp)
     (hydra-keyboard-macros/body))  "reverse" :color blue)
  ("'" edit-last-kbd-macro "edit")
  ("q" nil "quit"))
```

the blue head exits the hydra, and then the last command re-enters it after searching.